# How to scale every image in a list? pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pygame-surface

How do I scale every picture within a list in pygame?

I can't really figure it out. Whenever I try, an error says the item I am transform.scaling is a str or a bool and that I need a surface to work with. I understand that what I'm doing is wrong, but didn't hurt to try and I didn't know how to approach this. I am an amateur coder who just needs a little bit of help.

The relevant and most recent code:

```
rain_imgs = []
rain_list = ["1.png", "mv.png", "b1.png", "b3.png", "b4.png", "b5.png"]
for img in rain_list:
    rain_imgs.append(pg.image.load(path.join(img_folder, img)).convert())
    pg.transform.scale(img in rain_list, (60, 60))
```

The error:

```
TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not bool
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and follow the guidelines there to improve your question with sufficient information to describe and reproduce your problem. You may update the question with full list of code.

Comment: in `pg.transform.scale(img in rain_list, (60, 60))` The code `img in rain_list` returns bool, this is the source of your immediate error message.

Comment: As @PaulRooney mentioned, it should be `pg.transform.scale(img, (60, 60))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you're trying to use

```
pg.transform.scale(img in rain_list, (60, 60))
```

to refer to the item you've just put into the list.
unfortunately, the 'in' keyword when used solo just tells you whether the item exists in the designated array, which is where the error is coming from.
What you might want to do would look something like:

```
for img in rain_list:
  img_item = pg.image.load(path.join(img_folder, img)).convert()
  pg.transform.scale(img_item, (60, 60))
  rain_imgs.append(img_item)
```

Which, instead of having to yank the item back out of the list to alter it, creats a local object, alter its features, then stores it, without the boolean error cropping up.

====Edit===

Since it's now appending the original images, that tells me

```
pg.transform.scale(img_item, (60, 60))
```

Might be returning a new object, rather than running an alteration on the supplied one.
I would try something like:

```
for img in rain_list:
  img_item = pg.image.load(path.join(img_folder, img)).convert()
  rain_imgs.append(pg.transform.scale(img_item, (60, 60)))
```

see if that works.

Comment: ok, I see what you mean, but now when I try that, the images are staying the same size as the original pics.

Comment: Actually, I tried out the first example again and it worked (I had some other problem in the code). I haven't tried out the second one but, from the logic, it should work. Thank you for answering! Everything works just dandy now.

Answer (score -1):

Here's what I've been using:

```
scaled_rain_list = []

for img in rain_list:
scaled_rain_list.append(pygame.transform.scale(img,(60,60)))
```

This then makes the new list called 'scaled_rain_list' which stores all scaled up images.